# my wordpress images aren't displaying on firefox

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, firefox

I have built a website http://beyonddigital.mu/ which has been working for some time now, but suddenly images do not display from the site when i use a Firefox browser.

Please has anyone encountered this issue before on firefox

I read different tutorials online but no solution, please help

Comment: unrelated to programing. vote to close

Comment: really, so website browser issues are nt issues we can discuss here

Comment: it's your fault you don't check what format you are serving your images at. nobody can help you. it was very that if you are using `webp` and you don't see images, the first thing you do is google `webp browsers support`

Comment: agreed its my fault, my question is why we cant discuss such on this platform, and why u guys been so cheesy

Comment: because I am trying to help as many people as possible and it's not easy when so many questions (TONS) are not related to the scope of stackoverflow or are a simple user error, and it's not fair to run asking for help because people invest so much time in helping, it's fair to first try and "waste" your own time than theirs :) your question falls under the category of "user mistake", don't get mad.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're serving up images in the .webp format which is not supported by FF. No doubt some sort of optimiser plugin you're running that's converting them...

Comment: hmmm i see, ok ill try checkin and chngin